# sizeof anonymous nested struct

Tags: c, gcc, struct, nested

Suppose I have structure I'm using to model various packet formats:

```
#define MaxPacket 20

typedef struct {
    u8 packetLength;
    union {
        u8 bytes[MaxPacket];
        struct {
            u16 field1;
            u16 field2;
            u16 field3;
        } format1;
        struct {
            double value1;
            double value2;
        } format2;
    };
} Packet;
```

I can expect that `sizeof(Packet)` will be `21`. But is there any way to do something like:

```
sizeof(Packet.format2)
```

? I've tried that, but the compiler is not happy. Obviously, I could pull the `format1` out as a separate typedef and then I could `sizeof(format1)`. But I'm curious if I have to through all of that. I like the hierarchical composition of the formats. This is with gcc on an 8bit processor.

I'm equally interested if there's a way to use the nested type. IF I have to do a lot of

```
aPacketPointer->format2.value1; // not so onerous, but if the nesting gets deeper...
```

Then sometimes it would be nice to do:

```
Packet.format2 *formatPtr = &aPacketPointer->format2;
formatPtr->value2; // etc
```

Again, refactoring into a bunch of preceding typedefs would solve this problem, but then I lose the nice namespacing effect of the nested dotted references.

Comment: You might expect that `sizeof(Packet)` will be 21, but on at least two compiler configurations I've tried it on it comes out to 32. Maybe that won't be a problem for your use since at least it's larger than you expect (on the other hand, maybe it is a problem).  Something else that may surprise you is that the offset of the `union` containing `bytes`, `format` and `format2` was 8 - the compilers put padding between the `packetLength` field and the union.  You need to be very careful when modeling on-the-wire data objects in a C/C++ structure.

Comment: Bear in mind that @MichaelBurr was probably testing with a 32b architecture where everything gets padded by default. 8b processor compilers dont do padding. None that I have seen anyway.

Comment: Yes. Casting bytes as structs for the sake of over the wire protocols, starts with a basic assumption that you can force and trust your structure layouts. Different compilers have different mechanisms for doing this usually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something that will work even in C90, you can use a macro modeled on your toolchain's `offsetof()` macro:

```
#define sizeof_field(s,m) (sizeof((((s*)0)->m)))
```

Adjust it accordingly if your toolchain's `offsetof()` macro isn't based on casting `0` to a pointer to the structure's type.

When I use it like so:

```
std::cout << sizeof_field(Packet,format1) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof_field(Packet,format2) << std::endl;
```

I get the output:

```
6
16
```

For your second question, if you're willing to rely on GCC's `typeof` extension you can create a similar macro for declaring pointers to your nested anonymous structs:

```
#define typeof_field(s,m) typeof(((s*)0)->m)

...
typeof_field(Packet,format2)* f2 = &foo.format2;
```

To be honest, I find that construct pretty ugly, but it might still be better than other options you have available.

GCC documents that the "operand of typeof is evaluated for its side effects if and only if it is an expression of variably modified type or the name of such a type", so the apparent null pointer deference should not result in undefined behavior when a variable length array is not involved.

Comment: note: it is allowed to dereference null pointer inside sizeof in this case, because the operand of sizeof is not evaluated (since this is not a VLA).   (The same can't be said for user-defined offsetof clones)

Answer (score 3):

Using C11 or C99, create a dummy compound literal and seek its size.

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(   ((Packet){ 0, { "" }}).format2   ));
```

Output

```
16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just give those nested structs a name, no need for a typedef. Like this:

```
typedef struct {
    u8 packetLength;
    union {
        u8 bytes[MaxPacket];
        struct myformat1 {
            u16 field1;
            u16 field2;
            u16 field3;
        } format1;
        struct myformat2 {
            double value1;
            double value2;
        } format2;
    };
} Packet;
```

Then you can write e.g. `sizeof(struct myformat1)`, declare variables of that type, etc.

You could also add a typedef afterwards, e.g.

```
typedef struct myformat1 myformat1;
```